# Sharepoint 2007 Standard: Customizing Announcement Display Form

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, wss-3.0

I am trying to customize the DispForm.aspx Display form in an announcement list but as soon as I try to delte the WebPart and add the new Custom form using SharePoint Desginer 2007, the link to view an item on the list goes to root.

Example the correct URL for the item is:
 http://serverx/Site1/Lists/Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=2&Source=serverx%2FSit1%2FLists%2FAnnouncements%2FAllItems%2Easpx

After I edit the aspx page it goes here:
http://serverx/?ID=2

I followed the instructionsshown here:
http://www.risetime.com/blog/archive/2009/06/03/create-a-custom-newform-aspx-for-a-sharepoint-list.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually just hide the form control and add a custom one to the same page, this is the least buggy way

Comment: How do you hide the control? I tried commenting out the HTML tags but messed up the URL as well.

Comment: Changed the following to false: <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
And Worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Never** delete the default list form in a SharePoint list. See [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dszabo/custom-list-newform-aspx-ruined-in-wss-3-0) on how to recover.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you followed the step where you right click on DispForm.aspx and click "New from Existing Page"?

Also, after customizing your page, you have to change the properties of the list to use your new DispForm.

Comment: I modified the same aspx file (I made a backup just in case). Right clicking the list I access the Supporting Files tab and the "Display item form" is pointing to the correct file. The list is an announcement. The "Content type specific forms" opttion is set to "Announcement".